# WP7 Application.getResourceStream retunring null every time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, xna-4.0

Im trying to load a .txt file into a 2D array which i can do from a temp in isolated storage but our level builder writes to .txt files and moving them to isolated storage for each one is out of the question.

It is a windows phone game.

The text files Build action is set to content.

The Copy to output is set to Do Not Copy.

The file is in the base content folder.

```
        var ResrouceStream = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("grid_map;component/Data.txt", UriKind.Relative));
        if (ResrouceStream != null)
        {
          //do reading here
        }
```

I have a breakpoint on the if statment after it and when i check the var, it is still null and  later on it throughs a null error in `using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(ResrouceStream .Stream))`

because ResrouceStream  is null.

Ive tried most ways or reading a .txt file but this seams the best way

Comment: Why are you using this antiquated method of retrieving embedded resources in your application rather than using [project resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4(v=vs.110).aspx)?  *Did somebody tell you that this is how you do it?*  Just tell me the name of the man that touched you and *I will make him PAY.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to load the file with `Application.GetResourceStream`, you have to set its build action to `Resource`, not `Content`.

Comment: ok, so i changed the Build action from `Resource` to `Content` and it gave me the error:  `Project item 'obj\Windows Phone\Debug\grid_mapContent.g.resources' could not be built. Embedded Resource is not a supported Build Action for items in the Content subproject.`

Comment: Oh, that's because you're not supposed to put a text file in the content project. The content project is designed for files that need to be transformed in order to be used by the application (like textures). But if you really want to put the file there, set the build action to `Content`, set `Copy to output directory` to `Copy always`, then you can load the stream this way: `Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("content/Data.txt", UriKind.Relative));` Please don't tell anybody I'm the one who explained you that, my life would be endangered.