# Using .txt files as templates within visual studio project

Tags: .net, templates, text-files

I would like to have a few text files in a wpf application which are templates for Stata (a commercial statistics package) script files (.do). The files will contain 20-40 lines of Stata commands, and use <% %> as the replacement characters.

The obvious way (to me - bearing in mind I am an amateur) to do this is to have a folder named "TextTemplates", set the build action for the files within as Content, and then read in as a stream with something like

```
static string ReadTemplateFile(string fileName, IDictionary<string, string> replacements)
{
    var uri = new Uri("TextTemplates/" + fileName, UriKind.Relative);
    var resource = Application.GetContentStream(uri);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder((int)(resource.Stream.Length*1.3));
    string line;
    while ( ( line = sr.ReadLine() ) != null ) {
        int replaceStart = 0;
        while ((replaceStart = line.IndexOf("<%", replaceStart)) > -1)
        {
            int replaceEnd = line.IndexOf("%>", replaceStart) + 2;
            int replaceLength = replaceEnd - replaceStart -4;
            string replaceKey = line.Substring(replaceStart + 2, replaceLength).Trim();
            line = line.Substring(0, replaceStart) + replacements[replaceKey] + line.Substring(replaceEnd);
        }
        sb.AppendLine(line);
    }
    sr.Close();
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

However, I was getting a null value from GetResourceStream and came across this post on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244179/wp7-application-getresourcestream-retunring-null-every-time#14244360), where comments about doing this were beyond disparaging ("Did somebody tell you that this is how you do it? ... I will make him PAY." & "Please don't tell anybody I'm the one who explained you that, my life would be endangered.").

The 1 link (in the comment under the question) is no longer on MSDN. So how should I be doing this? The option of using a resx file does not seem that fantastic, as, when writing script it is nice to see a page at a time (rather than a line at a time, as when using the Managed Resources Editor), and tabs/spacing are so important when writing and editing the Stata script that defining a human unreadable const string is not that fantastic either.

I imagine things like email templates would face similar issues.

Thank you for explaining how best to approach this problem.

#### Edit

as an example, here is a template file

```
clear
insheet using "<%csvFile%>", <%delimiter%>
rename opvoralpolio opv
tempname a
foreach v of varlist dischargedatetime deathorlastcontactdatetime datetimebirth registeredat bcg-<%lastvax%> {
    capture confirm string variable `v'
    if (!_rc) {
        gen double `a' = clock( `v', "YMDhms#")
        drop `v'
        rename `a' `v'
        format `v' %tc
    }
}

capture confirm string variable lastweightdate
if (!_rc) {
    gen int `a' = date( lastweightdate, "YMD#")
    drop lastweightdate
    rename `a' lastweightdate
    format lastweightdate %td
}

label define causeOfDeathOption 0 Missing 1 Infection 2 "Congenital Malformation" 3 "Hyaline Membrane Disease" 4 "Intraventricular Haemorrhage" 5 "Necrotising Enterocollitis" 6 Other 7 Unknown
label define outcomeAt28DaysOption 0 Missing 1 "Inpatient At 28 Days" 2 "Died In Hospital Before 28 Days" 3 "Discharged Before 28 Days" 4 "Discharged And Known To Have Survived" 5 "Discharged And Known To Have Died" 6 "Discharged And Likely To Have Survived" 7 "Discharged And Likely To Have Died"
label define centreNames <%centreNames%>

label values causeofdeathid causeOfDeathOption
label values outcomeat28id outcomeAt28DaysOption
label values centreid centreNames

save "<%stataFile%>"
```

and here is a screenshot when using the Managed Resource Editor on the same text as above:

[image: Resx editor]

i.e. it is very difficult to debug or make useful edits to the file in this environment, and the same would apply to an email template with hand written HTML

Comment: I don't know why they remove the articles for VS2012 and beyond, but they still work or VS2010 and earlier. Use [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of the one that no longer works.

Comment: You probably want to investigate using the T4 templating engine to handle this.

Comment: Daniel, [run time T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee844259.aspx) must be the answer they were alluding to (I wasn't aware of these). Do you want to put it as a reply and I'll mark it as answered.